# Send an email to code reviewer when a code review is requested in TFS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

Is this possible? So whenever someone requests code review lists a code reviewer(s), is to possible to configure TFS to send emails to people who have been requested to do the review?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You can create a Code Review Alert for a team member.

First, you must configure an SMTP server to support TFS.

Second, you must be a member of the `Project Collection Administrator` or `Team Foundation Administrator` groups. If you’re not a member of these groups, you won't see the options available on `http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/teamproject/_admin/_alerts` for administering alerts.

- Choose the name of the team member from the drop down list, or type the name in the search box.

[image]

- Create a code review alert **A code review I am working on changes** for this team member. Then he will receive email alert when there is a review request to him.

Comment: We're using TFS 2018. Unfortunately, we don't receive a message, when someone requests a CR, that we were assigned to. We get the finished / comments notifications, but not the initial creation notification with the above answer. What could be wrong?